# Can't redirect with lot of variable- Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected. in

Tags: php, http-headers

This is my code:

```
$post_url="Location: http://webservices.plattformpartners.com/ilm/default.ashx?firstname=".$firstname."&lastname=".$lastname."&address=".$address1."&address2=".$address2."&zip=".$zip."&city=".$city."&state=".$state."&country=".$country;

header($post_url);
```

http://gedforadults.com/
on this page i am using this.

and i am getting this error when redirecting after form submit..
Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected. in /home/gedforad/public_html/index.php on line 60

So is there any way to redirect it with lot of variables?
when i use it within one or two variable its redirecting properly, but within lot of variable its generating error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the error: "new line detected".

I don't think the problem is too many variables. There is probably a new line in one of your variables. Try encoding your URL first and it should work fine:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php

Comment: i use this: $post_url=rawurlencode($post_url);
header($post_url); but now i am getting (500 Internal Server Error)..

Comment: That could be any number of things. You need to see what error you are getting in the logs.

Comment: its solved , there was problem with new line. i notice it now..
I can't vote you up bcoz stackoverflow don't allow me.Thanks for you help...

Comment: Sure, no problem. I know you can't upvote with a low level, but surely you can "accept" the answer, if you wish, by clicking the check mark. Anyway, glad it is fixed.