# can't redirect, "header may not contain more than a single header"

Tags: php, html, header, location

I want to redirect from my "log.php"  to "index.php", here's my code:

log.php -->

```
<?php
$com=shell_exec("ls -l");
if ($com==NULL) {
    echo "Can't execue the command :(";
}else{
    rawurlencode($com);
    header("Location: index.php?comm=$com");
}
?>
```

index.php

```
<p><button><a href="log.php">Files in folder</a></button></p>

<pre><?php 
    $command=$_GET['comm'];
    echo rawurldecode($command);
    ?>
</pre>
```

I tried it with 'urlencode()' too, but doesn't work neither.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954971/cant-redirect-with-lot-of-variable-header-may-not-contain-more-than-a-single-h

Comment: I've searched before doing my question, but didn't found a solution, so i asked my own =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are encoding `$com` variable, but you are not saving it anywhere.

Try `$com = urlencode($com);` instead.

And add `exit;` after `header()` redirect.