# How to fix Header new line error

Tags: php, header

I am receiving the following error message "Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected" I know it says that a new line has been detected, but I cannot figure where this line is coming from. I have tried to trim the variables..I have re-written the header line in different ways, without any result. I added the getallheaders function to see what was being passed, but I see no new line or any extra characters in the output $headers. Even using ob_start() does not help.

```
<?php
ob_start();
include "catalog.obj";

session_start(); 
$catalogObj = $_SESSION['catalogObj'];

if (isset($_POST['st']))
$st = $_POST['st'];
else
$st = '0';
if (isset($_POST['num']))
$num = $_POST['num'];
else
$num = '0';
if (isset($_POST['type']))
$type = $_POST['type'];
else
$type = '0';
if (isset($_POST['rec']))
$rec = $_POST['rec'];
else
$rec = '0';
if (isset($_POST['option']))
$option = $_POST['option'];
else
$option = '0';

if(strcmp($_POST['submit'],"Reset Form") == 0)
{
    header("location: search_catalog.php?type=$type&firstTime=1"); 
    exit; 
}
elseif(strcmp($_POST['submit'],"Catalog Administration") == 0)
{
    Header("Location: administration.php");
    exit;
}
else
{
    $inventory_id_num = $_POST['inventory_id_num'];
    $inventory_desc = $_POST['inventory_desc'];
    $inventory_revision = $_POST['inventory_revision'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $catalog_status_id = $_POST['catalog_status_id'];
    $order_form_type_id = $_POST['order_form_type_id'];

    $catalogObj->inventory_id_num = $inventory_id_num;
    $catalogObj->inventory_desc = $inventory_desc;
    $catalogObj->inventory_revision = $inventory_revision;
    $catalogObj->quantity = $quantity;
    $catalogObj->catalog_status_id = $catalog_status_id;
    //$catalogObj->order_form_type_id = array();
    $catalogObj->order_form_type_id = $order_form_type_id;

    $count=count($order_form_type_id);
    for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) 
    {
        //print "order_form_type_id: $order_form_type_id[$i]<br>";
        if(strlen($order_form_type_id[$i]) > 0)
        {
            $catalogObj->order_form_type_id[$i] = $order_form_type_id[$i];
        }
    }

    if(strcmp($_POST['submit'],"Back to Order Form") == 0)
    {
        Header("Location: order_form.php?num=$num");
        exit;
    } 
    else
    {
        //$url = "type=".$type."option=".$option."rec=".$rec."st=".$st."num=".$num;
        Header("location: search_catalog_handler.php?type=$type&option=$option&rec=$rec&st=$st&num=$num"); 
        //Header("location: search_catalog_handler.php?" . rawurlencode($url));
        if (function_exists('getallheaders'))
        {
            $headers = getallheaders();
            print_r( $headers);
        }       
        exit;
    }

}
    function getallheaders()
    {
           $headers = '';
       foreach ($_SERVER as $name => $value)
       {
           if (substr($name, 0, 5) == 'HTTP_')
           {
               $headers[str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_', ' ', substr($name, 5)))))] = $value;
           }
       }
       return $headers;
    }

?>
```

Comment: what is catalog.obj ??

Comment: By the looks of syntax highlighting here, this line may be at fault `Header("location: search_catalog_handler.php?type=$type&option=$option&rec=$rec&st=$st&num=$num");` and you're using `POST`. URL's as such should be, theoretically taken from a `GET`

Comment: This is the line causing the problem! I am updating a php site that was written 11 years ago. Half the time the original writer used posts to pass data used in the headers functions. as is the case here. I have been given three weeks to update 108 php code files that are similar to this...How do I fix this without rewriting everything?

Comment: Then try with `rawurlencode` as in `$type = rawurlencode($type); Header("location: search_catalog_handler.php?type=$type&option=$option&rec=$rec&st=$st&num=$num");` as found from an answer on SO [from this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8954971/1415724)

Comment: I found [this Q&A](http://www.webmaster-talk.com/threads/53578-Warning-Header-may-not-contain-more-than-a-single-header-new-line-detected) on another site. See entry `#4` yet you'll need to replace `ereg_replace` with `preg_replace` or `preg_match` equivalent.

Comment: I quote from [this page](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/warning-header-may-not-contain-more-than-a-single-header-1) *"I had this problem too. It turned out that I had an extra space at the end of my siteurl option. Once I removed the space it worked fine."* --- might be that too.

Comment: Another finding, talks about the location of `session_start();` Try moving it above `include "catalog.obj";`

Comment: Another thing you can do is look at the source of the document, and see if there are any of these in there `%20` you can also try using the [`headers_sent()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php) function. Also try doing a search inside all your code for `\n`

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that, because it may be a `space` issue, this `str_replace('_', ' ', substr($name, 5)` why is `_` being replaced by a space? Try `str_replace('_', '', substr($name, 5)` see if that helps. Other than everything I've shown you from my findings, I don't know what it could be. Do keep me posted, cheers.

Comment: Have a look at this answer I just found tonight, it could be relevant http://stackoverflow.com/a/20714378/1415724

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, thanks for the pointers! The problem in the above code was with the $st variable. I am not very experienced with headers and rewriting them but I had add the following conditinal statement:

```
if (!empty($_POST['st']))
{
    $st = $_POST['st'];
    $num = $_POST['num'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $rec = $_POST['rec'];
    $option = $_POST['option'];
}
```

To the beginning of my code, so it the complete code is:

```
<?php
ob_start();
/*************************************
altered complete 12/20/2013
rjm
*************************************/
include "catalog.obj";

session_start(); 
$catalogObj = $_SESSION['catalogObj'];
if (!empty($_POST['st']))
{
    $st = $_POST['st'];
    $num = $_POST['num'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $rec = $_POST['rec'];
    $option = $_POST['option'];
}

if(strcmp($_POST['submit'],"Reset Form") == 0)
{
    header("location: search_catalog.php?type=$type&firstTime=1"); 
    exit; 
}
elseif(strcmp($_POST['submit'],"Catalog Administration") == 0)
{
    Header("Location: administration.php");
    exit;
}
else
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST);
    echo "</pre>";
    //exit;
    $inventory_id_num = $_POST['inventory_id_num'];
    $inventory_desc = $_POST['inventory_desc'];
    $inventory_revision = $_POST['inventory_revision'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $catalog_status_id = $_POST['catalog_status_id'];
    $order_form_type_id = $_POST['order_form_type_id'];

    $catalogObj->inventory_id_num = $inventory_id_num;
    $catalogObj->inventory_desc = $inventory_desc;
    $catalogObj->inventory_revision = $inventory_revision;
    $catalogObj->quantity = $quantity;
    $catalogObj->catalog_status_id = $catalog_status_id;
    $catalogObj->order_form_type_id = $order_form_type_id;

    $count=count($order_form_type_id);
    for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) 
    {
        if(strlen($order_form_type_id[$i]) > 0)
        {
            $catalogObj->order_form_type_id[$i] = $order_form_type_id[$i];
        }
    }

    if(strcmp($_POST['submit'],"Back to Order Form") == 0)
    {
        Header("Location: order_form.php?num=$num");
        exit;
    } 
    else
    {
        Header("location: search_catalog_handler.php?type=$type&option=$option&rec=$rec&st=$st&num=$num"); 
        exit;
    }

}
?>
```

This allows for a specific type search (with parameters) and a general type search (no parameters) from the sending page.

Comment: Ah, so a `Happy Ending` after all. Glad to know you found your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `catalog.obj` does not output any information to the browser (which would result in an error as well), your `$type` variable looks like the culprit since it's the only wildcard.

*Note that you'll need to do the following for all `POST`ed variables in your script that you want to use in a URI:*

Sine it's possible that `$type` could be anything (it's using the `POST`ed variable sometimes), you should clean it up before spitting it back out in your header:

```
$type = urlencode($type); // Prepares the variable to be inserted in the URI
header("Location: search_catalog.php?type=$type&firstTime=1");
```

Comment: Sorry but this line of code is not the problem. this is "Header("location: search_catalog_handler.php?type=$type&option=$option&rec=$rec&st=$st&num=$num");‌​". Any suggestions? urlencode has not helped.

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump()` that whole string, starting with `search_catalog...`?

Comment: Sorry, I am having trouble printing out the header now. It is going through now, but not passing the params...If you don't mind I will get back with you in a little while, or first thing tomorrow. Long day...This has had me going in circles for a better part of the day.

Comment: here is what I am getting now"Array ( [Connection] => keep-alive [Content-Length] => 571 [Content-Type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded [Accept] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate [Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.5 [Cookie] => PHPSESSID=ru8p2punaaaqp9kkvtio622jh5 [Host] => www.gmacestest.com [Referer] => http://www.gmacestest.com/search_catalog.php?firstTime=1 [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0 )"