# Wordpress – HTML document does not start at line one

Tags: php, wordpress, output, removing-whitespace

I've been struggling with this problem for a long time now, but I cannot really find the solution. The problem is that `< !DOCTYPE html etc...` does not start at the first line, but leaves four blank lines before it starts.

All my files (`header.php`, `index.php` etc) have no line breaks before they start.

Anyone with any similar problems/experiences out there? It would have been of huge help!

See here for reference: view-source:http://2famous.tv/

Thank you

Comment: This may help you .... http://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-space-from-top-of-source-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most often not caused by *leading* but by *trailing* whitespace. Lots of old PHP code still closes down code at the end, which then all too often has a stray newline:

```
<?php

  // Lot of source code

?>   <----- and a newline here which is the culprit!
```

To avoid this issue, never close files with `?>` - PHP doesn't need it and will just stop parsing at EOF, thus implicitly avoid this 'garbage' in the output.

As for finding the files causing it - good luck, I'd start with combing any custom extensions for this and just removing all `?>` markers that you can find.

As an alternative, you can probably 'fix' it by adding a single `ob_start()` call to your `index.php`, and then in the template containing the doctype executing `ob_end_clean()` - this puts all intermediate output in the output buffers, and then trashes it.

Comment: OH MY GOD! Thank you so so soooo much! All I had to do was to remove the `?>`at the end of functions.php, and everything looks fine! I can't believe it was that easy!

So now I'm going to go over my PHP and clean it up! You really made my day. Thank you again!

Comment: Sure, you were just too fast for me. Had to way two minutes before I could accept it :P

Comment: *"To avoid this issue, never close files with `?>`"* – I'm curious. Is there a time when it does need to be closed? @NielsKeurentjes

Comment: No, it's an old habit from PHP3 days and before. I don't know precisely when they dropped it but it's probably 10 years ago. Never close a 'real' PHP file.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the added knowledge. I did heard say not so long ago that the `?>` should be left out when using classes, does that still apply? @NielsKeurentjes

Comment: Just never use `?>` unless you specifically need to start outputting raw HTML to the output stream. In any case.