# Warning in header function

Tags: php, php-5.3

I have the following piece of code

```
if ($_REQUEST['referer_url'] == "" ) {
  header("location: index.php");
  exit;
}
header('location: http://' . $_REQUEST['referer_url']);
exit;
```

And I get the error `Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected`. This is because in the header it adds a new line. I tried doing an `urlencode` like suggested here on stackoverflow, but it redirect me to a server not found error with an odd url containing an `undefined index` within the url. What else can I try in order to maintain the `$_REQUEST['referer_url']`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954971/cant-redirect-with-lot-of-variable-header-may-not-contain-more-than-a-single-h

Comment: `var_dump($_REQUEST['referer_url'])` - what do you get? Also, which of the two `header` calls produces the warning?

Comment: @HeroFTime same thing with `rawurlencode` - server not found...

Comment: @deceze I get `string(133) "
Notice: Undefined index: referer_url in /home/bartechc/public_html/admin/login.php on line 105
" `

Comment: maybe you mean `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];`

Comment: That is bizarre! Do you have some weird custom error reporting settings?! Anyway, it gives you a hint as to the error, right? Try with properly capitalised array indices. See `var_dump($_REQUEST)`.

Comment: HTTP uses line feeds to separate headers (and headers from body) thus a header value cannot contain a line feed. And you shouldn't inject raw input from untrusted sources in HTTP headers (or in SQL, HTML, JavaScript...) anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$redirect_url = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && 
                !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ?
                    $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : 'index.php';
header("Location: $redirect_url");
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

First need to check what you get in `$_REQUEST['referer_url']` if you have full url then remove `http://` from condition if blank  it will be redirect to index.php try

```
$redirect = (!empty($_REQUEST['referer_url']) ? 'http://'.$_REQUEST['referer_url'] : 'index.php');
header("location: $redirect");
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ever tried just to trim the referer?

http://php.net/trim

```
$myRefererUrl = trim($_REQUEST['referer_url']);    
header('location: '.(($myRefererUrl=='')?'index.php':$myRefererUrl));
exit;
```

With trim, you get rid of line breaks in strings ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try encoding your URL first and it should work fine: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php

Comment: Tried it and it redirect me to server not found + error.